# Importing queries from Access to PowerQuery

Tags: excel, import, powerquery, ms-access-2016

I am currently trying to import MSaccess 2016 queries into Excel 2016 powerquery, but am having issues with importing as I either get a blank screen or the MSAccess query does not show up at all on the PowerQuery list. Upon breaking down the MSaccess query to find the issue it seems like the columns that I have highlighted on the attached image is the problem is there anyway I can fix this?

If you require anymore info please let me know.

Kind Regards

[image]

There are two columns that I have highlighted in the attached image, when I remove then the query shows up, but unfortunately those columns are critical to get the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just ended up importing the necessary tables from access and merged them in powerquery. ended up working.